# Not able to java update json file using java jackson

Tags: java, jackson

json File is :

```
{   
    "id": 1,
    "name": "TC1",
    "steps": [
        {
            "stepId": 1,
            "action": "open",
            "object": "chrome",
            "input": "https://www.google.com/",

        }
    ]
}
```

and java code is :

```
public static void updateTestCaseValue(String tabTCPath) {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File jsonFile = new File(tabTCPath);
    try {
        JsonNode arrNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonFile).get("steps");
        if (arrNode.isArray()) {
            for (final JsonNode objNode : arrNode) {
                if(objNode.findPath("stepId").asText().equals("1")) {
                ((ObjectNode) objNode).put("object", "Firefox");
                }
                objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new File(tabTCPath), arrNode);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And output is:

```
[ {
  "stepId" : 1,
  "action" : "openBrowser1",
  "object" : "Firefox",
  "input" : "https://www.google.com/",
  "output" : "",
  "description" : "Open browser"
}]
```

but below part is not written to file

```
"id": 1,
"name": "TC1",
```

Comment: Right now, it's not clear what your issue is. If you're trying to write `id` and `name` to the output file, that's not happening because you're only getting the `steps` key. You'd need to repeat that part of your code to get the value of `id` and `name`

Comment: Thanks for response. I have to keep id and name as it is in file and only want to change single value from array.

Answer (score 3):

You lost reference to root `JsonNode`. You need to keep reference to root node. Also, write the result after `for-each` loop:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(json);
JsonNode steps = root.get("steps");
if (steps.isArray()) {
    for (final JsonNode item : steps) {
        if (item.findPath("stepId").asText().equals("1")) {
            ((ObjectNode) item).put("object", "Firefox");
        }
    }
    String resultJson = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root);
    System.out.println(resultJson);
}
```

Comment: Getting exception after running this code. com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'E': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Comment: @Baban, check your input `JSON`. It looks like it is invalid.

Comment: @Baban , I'm glad to hear that. Please, accept and upvote my answer, if it was helpful for you.

Comment: objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(jsonFile, resultJson);  This statement is writing to json file but inserting backslash after double quotes and no way to remove it. So I used Files.write( Paths.get(jsonFilePath), resultJson.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.DSYNC); and it worked without adding special charectors.

Comment: @Baban, In my example I just wanted to show how to generate the whole `JSON`. I am glad you could change it to version which works for you.